# Adding cusotm boxes inside my community site that link to to other sharepoint pages , and also link to external systems

Tags: 2013, page-layout

I have created new community site inside my SP 2013 server, and on the Category page , each category is displayed inside a box. now i need to add some Boxes to my home page that link to external systems, and to some SharePoint pages. so it there a way to insert custome Boxes inside SharePoint pages ? such as :-

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those boxes are called "Tiles" and it's super easy to spin up your own.

Go to the settings dropdown in top right > add an app > Promoted Links > fill in list data, drop on page, and presto

http://alinimer.com/2013/02/09/oob-creating-your-own-custom-tiles-in-sharepoint-2013/